# how to cast object of type '<TakeIterator>[System.Data.DataView]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i am using dataview and with it's skip and take methods, that will take 5 rows and skip some rows according to the page number and page size.

```
//creating a dataview object and assigning table[0]
dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
```

and next line in which i am facing error is:

```
dv=(DataView)dv.Cast<System.Data.DataView>().Skip((pageNum-1)*pageSize).Take(5);
```

At above line error occur is:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.Data.DataView]' to type 'System.Data.DataView'.
```

needs help. thanx.

Comment: are u dealing with anonymus objects  ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ??

Comment: sorry i am not getting you..can you explain a bit.

Comment: i am binding the gridview with dataview.

Comment: `DataView` is not `IEnumerable` of `DataView`, probably `DataRow` or `DataTable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works a little bit different, you can do the following:

```
        var dt = ds.Tables[0];
        dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip((pageNum - 1) * pageSize).Take(5).CopyToDataTable();

        var dv = new DataView(dt);
        GridView1.DataSource = dv;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Not forget the "using System.Data;" and if you have time look for LINQ...